# Time Formating In Python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm Trying To Run this code in python 3.8.2 but i have error invalid string
so what i'm supposed to used to do it right way
this is the code

```
import datetime 
data =datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%s%z')
print(data)
```

expect result like this

```
2020-05-19T15:20:21.327099399+0000
```

Comment: Please share the error. I do not see any errors in there and I tried running it in 3.8 env and it worked just fine.

Comment: Isn't datetime repeated? Shouldn't it be datetime.now(....) instead of datetime.datetime.now(...) ?

Comment: @Leo no it is not repeated. if you import a model you need to use it's name in code e.g. `import test; test.method()'. you would be correct if you used `from datetime import datetime' because it has a class also called datetime you can (and many do) import directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because `datetime` doesn't have a definition for `%s` milisecond only `%S` for seconds. you can use `%f` for microseconds

```py
import datetime
data =datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc).strftime('%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print(data)
```

**EDIT**
This should give you milliseconds

```py
import datetime
data =datetime.datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
print(data)
```

Comment: so how can i get milisecond  with it

Comment: TypeError: 'timespec' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: are you sure you typed it correctly? It works for me both in Pycharm and the python interpreter. Please show us exactly how you tried my answer and I will try to help